# Creating a markup system for my Android Firebase project

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android Firebase project, I want to build a view like this from a Firebase String resource.

> This is the first paragraph. Consisting of two string resource. And this is the second string resource attached to the first string forming a paragraph.
>
> "This is a quote formed using one string resource. But the quotation marks aren't the part of the resource."
>
> [image]

Now as stated in the example above I'll create the following string resource in Firebase Database. This is for reusability and ease of translation.

```
{
   "resources": {
       "-KaLdzKPi3zhL2ozW4HX": {
           "text": "This is the first paragraph. Consisting of two string resource."
       },
       "-KaR8EORN7Qvg3riT9IE": {
           "text": "And this is the second string resource attached to the first string forming a paragraph."
       },
       "-KaR8RIt0Gn1zt9BCFp2": {
           "text": "This is a quote formed using one string resource. But the quotation marks aren't the part of the resource."
       }
   }
}
```

Now if I replace each String resource with associated pushID and use a HTML/XML type markup system the example will look like:

```
<str pushID="-KaLdzKPi3zhL2ozW4HX"/> <str pushID="-KaR8EORN7Qvg3riT9IE"/>
<br/> 
<img srcID="-KaLdzKPi3zhL2ozW4HX"/> 
<br/>
"<str pushID="-KaLdzKPi3zhL2ozW4HX"/>"
```

And the firebase string will look like after escaping

```
{ "string" : "<str pushID=\"-KaLdzKPi3zhL2ozW4HX-\"/> <str pushID=\"-KaR8EORN7Qvg3riT9IE\"/> <br/> <img srcID=\"-KaLdzKPi3zhL2ozW4HX\"/> <br/>\"<str pushID=\"-KaLdzKPi3zhL2ozW4HX\"/> \"" }
```

As you can see there are too many extra characters and escape characters.

I can create my custom markup system like:

```
[str:-KaLdzKPi3zhL2ozW4HX]
```

or,

```
{str=-KaLdzKPi3zhL2ozW4HX}
```

My question is if you've ever done something similar what was your solution?
Which popular (and preferably integrated into JAVA) markup system can I use here?
If I have to create my own what is your suggestion that will have the least conflict with JSON, JAVA and will be bandwidth saving (unlike HTML/XML)?